# Godot: Making 3:2 viewport fit into changable sprite borders and fitting the screen without one

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I'm trying to implement a setting that would make a game fit into a frame with a toggle.

There are several issues that I've spent my whole evening trying to solve:

- I need to launch a game with any resolution setting and be sure that the viewport will resize to resolution's height while remaining the 3:2 aspect ratio
- When toggling a setting, a border should appear and the game screen should fit into it looking the same as it did before the toggle (UI and camera remain unchanged)
- The border sprite should adjust to game's resolution, that I thankfully accomplished

I attached an image to better explain what I mean:
https://imgur.com/a/uFEuQ9z

Right now I have following nodes: SubViewportContainer > SubViewport > Everything else, and on top of it is Border scene with a Canvas layer.

Here is the code that I have for now, although I don't think it's necessarily useful:

```
extends SubViewportContainer

@onready var sub_viewport = $SubViewport
@onready var border = %Border

func _ready():

    #Getting resolution info

    var game_width = DisplayServer.window_get_size().x
    var game_height = DisplayServer.window_get_size().y
    var game_resolution = DisplayServer.window_get_size()

    #Fitting a viewport size to game's resolution and centering it

    var viewport_height = game_height
    var viewport_width = game_height * 1.5

    $SubViewport.size = Vector2(viewport_width, viewport_height)
    self.size = Vector2(game_width,game_height)
    self.pivot_offset = Vector2(game_resolution.x, game_resolution.y) / 2
    self.position = Vector2((game_resolution.x - viewport_width) / 2, 0)
        
    #Prints for checking if everything works as intended
        
    print(str(game_width) + ": game width")
    print(str(game_height) + ": game height")
    print(str(viewport_width) + ": viewport width")
    print(str(viewport_height) + ": viewport height")
```

Prints do return correct numbers whenever I change the resolution (I tried 720, 1080, 1440, 800p).

However, the camera zooms out and the UI doesn't scale to new viewport.

Any input would be much appreciated. Thank you.